# Reverse Array Queries given

Tags: arrays, reverse

For a given array of integers, perform operations on the array. Return the resulting array after all operations have been applied in the order given. Each operation contains two indices. Reverse the subarray between those zero-based indices, inclusive.

1: arr is : [1, 2, 3] 1: operations is : [[0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 2]]

2: arr is : [640, 26, 276, 224, 737, 677, 893, 87, 422, 30] 2: operations is : [[0, 9], [2, 2], [5, 5], [1, 6], [5, 6], [5, 9], [0, 8], [6, 7], [1, 9], [3, 3]]
can any one help in solving this question.

Comment: Do it by hand on paper first, every step a new line, indenting appropriately and such. Then implement this by code.

Answer (score 0):

Start like this:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> [3, 2, 1]  # first: reverse array between index 0 and 2
          -> [3, 1, 2]  # then:  reverse array between index 1 and 2
etc.
```

I hope you got the idea.